# aiogram message handler not firing for a message containing media

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I am using aiogram 2.11.2 as Python interface to the Telegram API, but I am encountering an issue in the simplest callback: it does activate when the message is text only, but fails whenever any media is attached. This includes photos, videos, audios, stickers and GIFs, with or without caption.

I hope I'm not missing out on something.

```
import aiogram


class TelegramBot(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.bot = aiogram.Bot(token="TOKEN")
        self.dispatcher = aiogram.Dispatcher(bot=self.bot)
        self.dispatcher.register_message_handler(self.on_msg,)
    
    async def on_msg(self, msg: aiogram.types.Message):
        print("Message received in telegram")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I was really missing out on something. To listen for all kinds of messages, it is sufficient to define `content_type` as

```
dispatcher.register_message_handler(self.on_msg, content_type=aiogram.types.ContentType.all())
```

Thanks to the [answerer to my Git issue](https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/issues/570#issuecomment-826606486).